# OpenSC vs openCryptoKI

Tags: c, smartcard, pkcs#11, opensc

Which library is more popular for Linux and Mac OS operating systems and what advantages and disadvantages there are for supporting PKCS#11 standard for smart cards?
Is there any tutorial about adding PKCS#11 support for smart cards?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSC is a software stack for smart cards. And it includes a PKCS#11 module. OpenCryptoki is "just" a PKCS#11 module (meaning software-only-module, except for some IBM PCI cards, apparently) that has nothing to do with (most) smart cards.

Your card probably comes with a PKCS#11 module for at least Windows. PKCS#11 is just a software interface, much like a PAM module. What happens below the API is a different story.

You might start with OpenSC wiki and mailing list, if your aim is smart cards.

Comment: Thank you Martin for information.I need to implement PKCS#11 module for specific smart card. There is slot manager for controlling different PKCS#11 modules and I need to know which library provides best slot manager under linux.